# Dataset returns undefined (not in console)

Tags: javascript, dataset

I struggle with this simple thing:
Body tag looks like this:

```
<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-12 page-parent logged-in admin-bar elementor-default elementor-kit-77 elementor-page elementor-page-12 customize-support" data-elementor-device-mode="tablet">
```

When I put `console.log(document.querySelector('body').dataset.elementorDeviceMode);` directly in chrome console, I get "tablet". When I put the same line of code into my js file, I get "undefined".

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think in chrome because it's rendered not like in your js code it's not running or getting value

Comment: I think I've found the solution. I've replaced jquery ```jQuery(document).ready(function ($)``` to ``` document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) ```